# PHP CMS/Blog Platform with easy standalone HTML template integration

Tags: web-apps, html, php, cms, blog

I'm looking for a PHP CMS or Blogging platform that is easy to implement standalone HTML templates into. I have purchased a HTML template which comes with example blog and single post pages and am wanting to use this with a cms/blog platform.

I have come across one platform in which you enter a few lines that you wrap around certain areas, such as the blog content, comments etc and then the platform actively takes over.

Unfortunately I didn't save the name of such software, but I'm hoping some other people have stumbled across it - or similar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research and change of keywords, I found the software I was looking for, [CouchCMS](http://couchcms.com).

The features I have mentioned, use of a standalone template and the platform actively taking control over this, can be seen in the documentation provided by CouchCMS [here](http://docs.couchcms.com/tutorials/portfolio-site.html).